# No response when clicking button with casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

For some reason whenever I attempt to click a button using CasperJS it never actually responds. I render a screenshot and it acts as if it never clicked it at all.

```
phantom.casperPath = './modules/';
phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath +'/bin/bootstrap.js');
var system = require('system');
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').selectXPath;

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 1080};

casper.start();
casper.thenOpen('https://mydomain.com', function(){
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.fill('form#loginPage',{
        'user_name': 'myuser',
        'user_password': 'mypassword'
    },false);
    casper.wait(100);
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.click('#sysverb_login');
    casper.wait(100);
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.capture('test.png');
    this.echo('success');
    this.exit();
});
casper.run(function() {
});
```

Comment: What do you expect happening after you click the button (new page is loaded, something happens on the page ...)? Please fix your formatting.

Comment: try moving the capture into its own then or add a pause before the capture

Comment: I tried adding a pause, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not advised to use `then` after a page is loaded, I [quote from the docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#then):-

> Step functions added to then() are processed in two different cases:
>
> 1. When the previous step function has been executed,
> 2. when the previous main HTTP request has been executed and the page loaded;
>
> Note that
>   there’s no single definition of page loaded; is it when the DOMReady
>   event has been triggered? Is it “all requests being finished”? Is it
>   *all application logic being performed”? Or “all elements being rendered”? The answer always depends on the context. Hence why you’re
>   encouraged to always use the waitFor() family methods to keep explicit
>   control on what you actually expect.
>
> A common trick is to use waitForSelector():

try (replace SOMESELECTOR with a selector that is visible on page after the post back happens):-

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.fill('form#loginPage',{
        'user_name': 'myuser',
        'user_password': 'mypassword'
    },false);
});

casper.then(function(){
  this.click('#sysverb_login');
});

casper.waitForSelector("SOMESELECTOR", function(){
  this.capture('test.png');
  this.echo('success');
  this.exit();
});
```